# How to add a <script> attribute in Slim

Tags: javascript, html, slim-lang

Trying to get Slim (slim-lang.com) to render this:

`<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXXXX-X"></script>`

I thought this would work:

`script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXXXX-X"`

But that yields:

`<script>async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXXXX-X"</script>`

Of course I typing the original in to a .slim file works but I'd like to know how to do this "correctly".

Comment: maybe `async="true"` will work?

Comment: `async=true` works for me